R issue with the same random effect variance value (sigma^2) in sjPlot::tab_model() for two separate glmmTMB models
I have two glmmTMB models fit with binomial distributions that I am attempting to display their model summary output using sjPlot::tab_model()
Databases, Models, and tab_model() code
library(glmmTMB)
library(sjPlot)

########## PC_1_5 Survival Analyses with Module Sides Combined (N & S) ###############

PC_1_5_survival_data <- structure(list(TimeStep = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12), Year = c("17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", 
"18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", 
"18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", 
"19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", 
"19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", 
"19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", 
"19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "20", 
"20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20"), Season = c("fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "winter", "winter", 
"winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "spring", "spring", "spring", 
"summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", 
"summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "winter", "winter", 
"winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", 
"winter", "spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", 
"spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", "summer", "summer", "summer", 
"summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", 
"summer", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "winter", "winter", "winter", 
"winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", 
"winter", "spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", 
"spring", "spring", "spring", "spring"), `Taxonomic Code` = c("PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC"), 
    Quarter = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
    3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
    7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
    9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), Site_long = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Waikiki", "Hanauma Bay"
    ), class = c("ordered", "factor")), Shelter = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Low", "High"
    ), class = c("ordered", "factor")), `Module #` = c(213, 215, 
    111, 115, 112, 114, 116, 213, 215, 113, 115, 112, 114, 215, 
    113, 112, 213, 215, 214, 216, 111, 113, 115, 112, 114, 116, 
    213, 215, 212, 214, 216, 111, 113, 115, 112, 116, 213, 215, 
    212, 216, 111, 113, 115, 112, 114, 116, 213, 215, 214, 216, 
    111, 113, 115, 112, 114, 116, 213, 215, 212, 214, 216, 111, 
    113, 115, 112, 114, 116, 213, 215, 212, 214, 216, 111, 113, 
    115, 112, 114, 116, 213, 215, 212, 214, 216, 111, 113, 115, 
    112, 114, 116, 213, 215, 212, 214, 216, 111, 113, 115, 112, 
    114), total_corals_new = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 12L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 
    8L, 13L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 1L, 6L, 9L, 5L, 26L, 1L, 1L, 
    12L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 13L, 14L, 13L, 14L, 5L, 8L, 16L, 14L, 13L, 
    14L, 34L, 15L, 18L, 12L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 13L, 7L, 
    12L, 12L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 14L, 
    3L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 6L), survive_new = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    6L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 
    4L, 21L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 10L, 13L, 6L, 12L, 3L, 3L, 
    9L, 13L, 9L, 11L, 16L, 14L, 11L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 12L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Survival_prop_new = c(1, 
    1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.777777777777778, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0.333333333333333, 1, 0.545454545454545, 1, 0, 1, 0.75, 0.4, 
    1, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 1, 0.166666666666667, 
    0.857142857142857, 0.4, 0, 0.375, 1, 0.666666666666667, 1, 
    1, 1, 0.25, 0.615384615384615, 0.25, 0.2, 0.4, 0.666666666666667, 
    0.7, 1, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.8, 0.807692307692308, 
    1, 1, 0.75, 1, 0.875, 0.75, 0.769230769230769, 0.928571428571429, 
    0.461538461538462, 0.857142857142857, 0.6, 0.375, 0.5625, 
    0.928571428571429, 0.692307692307692, 0.785714285714286, 
    0.470588235294118, 0.933333333333333, 0.611111111111111, 
    0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.571428571428571, 0.5, 0.833333333333333, 
    0.461538461538462, 0.142857142857143, 0.583333333333333, 
    0.416666666666667, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0.5, 0.4, 1, 0.6, 0.285714285714286, 
    0.75, 0.333333333333333, 0.857142857142857, 0.666666666666667, 
    1, 0.666666666666667, 0.571428571428571, 0.666666666666667, 
    0.6, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 0.5), `%_Survival` = c(100, 
    100, 100, 50, 50, 77.7777777777778, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
    100, 100, 100, 33.3333333333333, 100, 54.5454545454545, 100, 
    0, 100, 75, 40, 100, 33.3333333333333, 66.6666666666667, 
    100, 16.6666666666667, 85.7142857142857, 40, 0, 37.5, 100, 
    66.6666666666667, 100, 100, 100, 25, 61.5384615384615, 25, 
    20, 40, 66.6666666666667, 70, 100, 33.3333333333333, 66.6666666666667, 
    80, 80.7692307692308, 100, 100, 75, 100, 87.5, 75, 76.9230769230769, 
    92.8571428571429, 46.1538461538462, 85.7142857142857, 60, 
    37.5, 56.25, 92.8571428571429, 69.2307692307692, 78.5714285714286, 
    47.0588235294118, 93.3333333333333, 61.1111111111111, 66.6666666666667, 
    66.6666666666667, 66.6666666666667, 33.3333333333333, 57.1428571428571, 
    50, 83.3333333333333, 46.1538461538462, 14.2857142857143, 
    58.3333333333333, 41.6666666666667, 100, 0, 0, 100, 50, 40, 
    100, 60, 28.5714285714286, 75, 33.3333333333333, 85.7142857142857, 
    66.6666666666667, 100, 66.6666666666667, 57.1428571428571, 
    66.6666666666667, 60, 33.3333333333333, 50, 50), Survival_prop = c(1, 
    1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.777777777777778, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0.333333333333333, 1, 0.545454545454545, 1, 0, 1, 0.75, 0.4, 
    1, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 1, 0.166666666666667, 
    0.857142857142857, 0.4, 0, 0.375, 1, 0.666666666666667, 1, 
    1, 1, 0.25, 0.615384615384615, 0.25, 0.2, 0.4, 0.666666666666667, 
    0.7, 1, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.8, 0.807692307692308, 
    1, 1, 0.75, 1, 0.875, 0.75, 0.769230769230769, 0.928571428571429, 
    0.461538461538462, 0.857142857142857, 0.6, 0.375, 0.5625, 
    0.928571428571429, 0.692307692307692, 0.785714285714286, 
    0.470588235294118, 0.933333333333333, 0.611111111111111, 
    0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.571428571428571, 0.5, 0.833333333333333, 
    0.461538461538462, 0.142857142857143, 0.583333333333333, 
    0.416666666666667, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0.5, 0.4, 1, 0.6, 0.285714285714286, 
    0.75, 0.333333333333333, 0.857142857142857, 0.666666666666667, 
    1, 0.666666666666667, 0.571428571428571, 0.666666666666667, 
    0.6, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 0.5), survival_trans = c(3.66356164612965, 
    3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 0, 0, 1.17411984117625, 
    3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 
    3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 
    -0.693147180559945, 3.66356164612965, 0.173158643872435, 
    3.66356164612965, -3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 1.0330150061823, 
    -0.384674338439091, 3.66356164612965, -0.655875785762714, 
    0.655875785762714, 3.66356164612965, -1.6094379124341, 1.79175946922805, 
    -0.384674338439091, -3.66356164612965, -0.484245985961279, 
    3.66356164612965, 0.655875785762714, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 
    3.66356164612965, -1.09861228866811, 0.470003629245736, -1.09861228866811, 
    -1.38629436111989, -0.405465108108164, 0.693147180559945, 
    0.847297860387203, 3.66356164612965, -0.655875785762714, 
    0.655875785762714, 1.38629436111989, 1.43508452528932, 3.66356164612965, 
    3.66356164612965, 1.0330150061823, 3.66356164612965, 1.78448670989897, 
    1.09861228866811, 1.20397280432594, 2.56494935746154, -0.154150679827258, 
    1.79175946922805, 0.405465108108164, -0.510825623765991, 
    0.251314428280906, 2.56494935746154, 0.810930216216329, 1.29928298413026, 
    -0.117783035656384, 2.63905732961526, 0.451985123743057, 
    0.693147180559945, 0.693147180559945, 0.693147180559945, 
    -0.693147180559945, 0.287682072451781, 0, 1.6094379124341, 
    -0.154150679827258, -1.79175946922805, 0.336472236621213, 
    -0.336472236621213, 3.66356164612965, -3.66356164612965, 
    -3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 0, -0.384674338439091, 
    3.66356164612965, 0.384674338439091, -0.916290731874155, 
    1.09861228866811, -0.693147180559945, 1.79175946922805, 0.693147180559945, 
    3.66356164612965, 0.655875785762714, 0.27311365662349, 0.693147180559945, 
    0.405465108108164, -0.693147180559945, 0, 0)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -99L), groups = structure(list(
    TimeStep = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12), Year = c("17", "17", "17", 
    "17", "17", "17", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", 
    "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "19", "19", 
    "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", 
    "19", "19", "19", "19", "20", "20", "20", "20"), Season = c("fall", 
    "fall", "fall", "winter", "winter", "winter", "spring", "spring", 
    "spring", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", 
    "fall", "fall", "fall", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", 
    "spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", "summer", "summer", 
    "summer", "summer", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "winter", 
    "winter", "winter", "winter", "spring", "spring", "spring", 
    "spring"), `Taxonomic Code` = c("PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
    "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
    "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
    "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
    "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC"), Quarter = c(1, 1, 1, 
    2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
    7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 
    11, 11), Site_long = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Waikiki", "Hanauma Bay"), class = c("ordered", 
    "factor")), Shelter = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("Low", "High"), class = c("ordered", 
    "factor")), .rows = structure(list(5:7, 3:4, 1:2, 12:13, 
        10:11, 8:9, 16L, 15L, 14L, 24:26, 21:23, 19:20, 17:18, 
        35:36, 32:34, 29:31, 27:28, 44:46, 41:43, 39:40, 37:38, 
        54:56, 51:53, 49:50, 47:48, 65:67, 62:64, 59:61, 57:58, 
        76:78, 73:75, 70:72, 68:69, 87:89, 84:86, 81:83, 79:80, 
        98:99, 95:97, 92:94, 90:91), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -41L), .drop = TRUE))

# all corals
module_survival <- as.numeric(PC_1_5_survival_data$`Module #`)
PC_1_5_survival_data$Site_long <- factor(PC_1_5_survival_data$Site_long, levels = c("Waikiki", "Hanauma Bay"), ordered = TRUE)
PC_1_5_survival_data$Shelter <- factor(PC_1_5_survival_data$Shelter, levels = c("Low", "High"), ordered = TRUE) 
# factorize variables

# DHARMa simulated model and Q-Q plots
####################
PC_1_5_survival_glmmTMB <- glmmTMB(Survival_prop ~ Site_long*Shelter + (1|module_survival) + (1|Year/Season), data = PC_1_5_survival_data, na.action = "na.fail", family = "binomial", weights = total_corals_new)
summary(PC_1_5_survival_glmmTMB)


########### PC 6_10 Survival Analyses with Module Sides Combined (N & S) ###############

PC_6_10_survival_data <- structure(list(TimeStep = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12), Year = c("17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", 
"18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", 
"18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", 
"18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "19", "19", "19", 
"19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", 
"19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", 
"19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", 
"19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", 
"20", "20"), Season = c("fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "winter", "winter", 
"winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", 
"winter", "spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", 
"spring", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", 
"summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", 
"winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "spring", "spring", "spring", 
"spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", "summer", 
"summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", 
"summer", "summer", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "winter", "winter", "winter", 
"winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", 
"winter", "spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", 
"spring", "spring"), `Taxonomic Code` = c("PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC"), Quarter = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11), Site_long = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Waikiki", "Hanauma Bay"
), class = c("ordered", "factor")), Shelter = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Low", 
"High"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), `Module #` = c(213, 
215, 212, 214, 216, 111, 113, 115, 112, 114, 116, 213, 215, 212, 
216, 111, 113, 115, 112, 114, 116, 214, 216, 111, 113, 112, 114, 
116, 213, 215, 212, 214, 111, 113, 115, 112, 114, 116, 213, 215, 
212, 214, 216, 111, 113, 115, 112, 114, 116, 213, 215, 212, 214, 
216, 111, 113, 115, 112, 114, 116, 215, 214, 216, 111, 113, 115, 
112, 114, 116, 213, 215, 212, 216, 111, 113, 115, 112, 114, 116, 
213, 215, 212, 214, 216, 111, 113, 115, 112, 114, 116, 213, 215, 
212, 214, 216, 111, 113, 115, 112, 114, 116, 213, 215, 212, 214, 
216, 113, 114, 116), total_corals_new = c(4L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 13L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 9L, 6L, 12L, 6L, 7L, 12L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 13L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 21L, 4L, 13L, 
1L, 2L, 5L, 18L, 11L, 16L, 13L, 11L, 21L, 11L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 
8L, 12L, 8L, 2L, 10L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 1L), survive_new = c(4L, 
7L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 12L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 11L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 11L, 
19L, 4L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 9L, 14L, 12L, 9L, 11L, 6L, 5L, 
3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 
3L, 0L), Survival_prop_new = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.857142857142857, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.769230769230769, 0.666666666666667, 
0.5, 1, 1, 0.666666666666667, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.8, 0.8, 
1, 0.8, 1, 1, 1, 0.857142857142857, 1, 1, 1, 0.875, 1, 0.5, 1, 
0.857142857142857, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.666666666666667, 1, 
0.75, 0.833333333333333, 0.714285714285714, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.8, 
1, 0.636363636363636, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.846153846153846, 0.5, 0.8, 
1, 1, 1, 0.8, 1, 0.904761904761905, 1, 0.923076923076923, 1, 
1, 0.6, 0.555555555555556, 0.818181818181818, 0.875, 0.923076923076923, 
0.818181818181818, 0.523809523809524, 0.545454545454545, 1, 0.75, 
0.666666666666667, 0.833333333333333, 0.5, 0.833333333333333, 
0.25, 0.5, 0.4, 0.625, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.833333333333333, 1, 
0), `%_Survival` = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 50, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
85.7142857142857, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
76.9230769230769, 66.6666666666667, 50, 100, 100, 66.6666666666667, 
100, 0, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 80, 80, 100, 80, 100, 100, 100, 
85.7142857142857, 100, 100, 100, 87.5, 100, 50, 100, 85.7142857142857, 
50, 100, 100, 50, 100, 100, 66.6666666666667, 100, 75, 83.3333333333333, 
71.4285714285714, 100, 100, 100, 100, 80, 100, 63.6363636363636, 
100, 100, 100, 0, 84.6153846153846, 50, 80, 100, 100, 100, 80, 
100, 90.4761904761905, 100, 92.3076923076923, 100, 100, 60, 55.5555555555556, 
81.8181818181818, 87.5, 92.3076923076923, 81.8181818181818, 52.3809523809524, 
54.5454545454545, 100, 75, 66.6666666666667, 83.3333333333333, 
50, 83.3333333333333, 25, 50, 40, 62.5, 100, 100, 100, 100, 50, 
83.3333333333333, 100, 0), Survival_prop = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0.857142857142857, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.769230769230769, 
0.666666666666667, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.666666666666667, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 0.8, 1, 1, 1, 0.857142857142857, 1, 1, 
1, 0.875, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.857142857142857, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 
0.666666666666667, 1, 0.75, 0.833333333333333, 0.714285714285714, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0.8, 1, 0.636363636363636, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.846153846153846, 
0.5, 0.8, 1, 1, 1, 0.8, 1, 0.904761904761905, 1, 0.923076923076923, 
1, 1, 0.6, 0.555555555555556, 0.818181818181818, 0.875, 0.923076923076923, 
0.818181818181818, 0.523809523809524, 0.545454545454545, 1, 0.75, 
0.666666666666667, 0.833333333333333, 0.5, 0.833333333333333, 
0.25, 0.5, 0.4, 0.625, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.833333333333333, 1, 
0), survival_trans = c(3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 
3.66356164612965, 0, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 
3.66356164612965, 1.65292302437384, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 
3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 
3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 1.12962252541067, 
0.655875785762714, 0, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 0.655875785762714, 
3.66356164612965, -3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 
3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 1.29504568965475, 
1.29504568965475, 3.66356164612965, 1.29504568965475, 3.66356164612965, 
3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 1.65292302437384, 3.66356164612965, 
3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 1.78448670989897, 3.66356164612965, 
0, 3.66356164612965, 1.65292302437384, 0, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 
0, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 0.655875785762714, 3.66356164612965, 
1.0330150061823, 1.49392502531226, 0.86436312094139, 3.66356164612965, 
3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 1.29504568965475, 
3.66356164612965, 0.530267305380576, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 
3.66356164612965, -3.66356164612965, 1.57747172037161, 0, 1.38629436111989, 
3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 1.29504568965475, 
3.66356164612965, 2.03598506621438, 3.66356164612965, 2.21877713572195, 
3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 0.384674338439091, 0.22314355131421, 
1.50407739677627, 1.94591014905531, 2.484906649788, 1.50407739677627, 
0.0953101798043249, 0.173158643872435, 3.66356164612965, 1.09861228866811, 
0.693147180559945, 1.6094379124341, 0, 1.6094379124341, -1.09861228866811, 
0, -0.405465108108164, 0.510825623765991, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 
3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 0, 1.6094379124341, 3.66356164612965, 
-3.66356164612965)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -109L), groups = structure(list(
    TimeStep = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12), Year = c("17", "17", 
    "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "18", "18", "18", "18", 
    "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", "18", 
    "18", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", 
    "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "20", "20", "20", 
    "20"), Season = c("fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "winter", 
    "winter", "winter", "winter", "spring", "spring", "spring", 
    "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
    "fall", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "spring", 
    "spring", "spring", "spring", "summer", "summer", "summer", 
    "summer", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "winter", "winter", 
    "winter", "winter", "spring", "spring", "spring", "spring"
    ), `Taxonomic Code` = c("PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
    "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
    "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
    "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
    "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC"), Quarter = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 11, 11, 11, 11), Site_long = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Waikiki", 
    "Hanauma Bay"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), Shelter = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("Low", 
    "High"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), .rows = structure(list(
        9:11, 6:8, 3:5, 1:2, 19:21, 16:18, 14:15, 12:13, 26:28, 
        24:25, 22:23, 36:38, 33:35, 31:32, 29:30, 47:49, 44:46, 
        41:43, 39:40, 58:60, 55:57, 52:54, 50:51, 67:69, 64:66, 
        62:63, 61L, 77:79, 74:76, 72:73, 70:71, 88:90, 85:87, 
        82:84, 80:81, 99:101, 96:98, 93:95, 91:92, 108:109, 107L, 
        104:106, 102:103), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -43L), .drop = TRUE))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ), row.names = c(NA, -43L), .drop = TRUE))

# all corals
module_survival <- as.numeric(PC_6_10_survival_data$`Module #`)
PC_6_10_survival_data$Site_long <- factor(PC_6_10_survival_data$Site_long, levels = c("Waikiki", "Hanauma Bay"), ordered = TRUE)
PC_6_10_survival_data$Shelter <- factor(PC_6_10_survival_data$Shelter, levels = c("Low", "High"), ordered = TRUE) 
# factorize variables

# DHARMa simulated model and Q-Q plots
####################
PC_6_10_survival_glmmTMB <- glmmTMB(Survival_prop ~ Site_long*Shelter + (1|module_survival) + (1|Year/Season), data = PC_6_10_survival_data, na.action = "na.fail", family = "binomial",, weights = total_corals_new)
summary(PC_6_10_survival_glmmTMB)


### tab_model()
tab_model(PC_1_5_survival_glmmTMB, PC_6_10_survival_glmmTMB, pred.labels = c("Site", "Shelter", "Site x Shelter"), dv.labels = c("PC 1-5 Survival", "PC 6-10 Survival"), show.re.var = TRUE, show.ngroups = FALSE, show.icc = FALSE, show.intercept = FALSE, show.est = TRUE, show.se = TRUE, show.df = TRUE, show.stat = TRUE, show.p = TRUE, df.method = NULL, p.val = "satterthwaite", show.ci = FALSE, string.est = "Estimate", string.se = "SE", string.df = "df", string.stat = "t value", string.p = "p", col.order = c("est", "se", "stat", "p"), transform = NULL)

Output

Notice how between these two different models with different estimates for the predictors, the random effects variances (sigma^2) are exactly the same for both models.  I am trying to understand why this is and if this is reflective of how glmmTMB assesses variance explained by random effects or if there is a conflict with tab_model() that falsely shows the sigma^2 this way.

This takes a lot of digging, but these variances are not the 'random effects' variance, but rather an approximation of the variance of the conditional distribution (equivalent to the residual variance in the case of a linear mixed model). This is a bit tricky to figure out, but it turns out that these values are both exactly $\pi^2/3 = 3.289868 ... \approx 3.29$, which is a constant for Bernoulli (i.e. binomial with $N=1$) responses: the underlying code is here.
I believe this is explained by Nakagawa and Schielzeth (2013).
Nakagawa, Shinichi, and Holger Schielzeth. “A General and Simple Method for Obtaining $R^2$ from Generalized Linear Mixed-Effects Models.” Methods in Ecology and Evolution 4, no. 2 (February 1, 2013): 133–42. https://doi.org/10.1111/j.2041-210x.2012.00261.x.

Thank you very much Ben for your response.  Looked up this reference and it appears to be the foundational paper for r.squaredGLMM().

Yes, that's right. (There's a slightly later paper with Johnson, Nakagawa and Schielzeth [in some order] that further extends the framework.)
